# Is it possible to encapsulate a [Authorize] tag in an if statement?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, forms-authentication

I am using [Authorize] tags at the top of my controller methods to verify a user is able to view the page and use it. I have a test instance that I am unable to use the login so I have to comment out the tag to be able to test functionality. But then when I deploy the project to a server I have to uncomment the tags so they take into effect. I am wondering if it is possible to create a config value that I can check whether it is true or false and based on the if statement it determines if it uses [Authorize] or [AllowAnonymous]. I imagine the code looking like this:

```
namespace UI.Controllers
{
    if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serverState"] == "true")
       [Authorize]
    else
       [AllowAnonymous]

    public class ConfigurationController : Controller
    {
       ...
```

Comment: Could you accomplish this by `#define DEBUG` and using an `#if DEBUG` directive?

Comment: Yes. Thank you that worked. I didn't consider that option.

Comment: Glad it worked.

Comment: Of course this would mean that you disable security if you inadvertently deploy a debug build.  Another option is to create a principal with the necessary authorization earlier on in the request processing, for example in Global.asax Authenticate_Request or Authorize_Request.  You would have more flexibility for deciding how to activate the fake principal, e,g,  based on an appSetting as in your sample code.

Comment: I deploy to a test server first and run through checks before I put it onto a production server so I will catch if I had deployed a debug package. I also wont every change the type of package when I generate for deployment. I appreciate your concern but I do not think I will run into that mistake.